# Delphi XE4, wParam for TControl.Perform() accepts only unsigned int?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

In Delphi7, `TControl.Perform()` accepts negative values for the `wParam` parameter, and this is how it's supposed to do, since for example, the [EM_LINEFROMCHAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761609(v=vs.85).aspx)  winapi message would expect `-1` for `wParam`.

But under Delphi XE4, the data type for `wParam` has changed to `NativeUInt`, which would not accept negative integers.

This is a bug of the Delphi RTL, or I'm understand it wrongly? Thanks.

Comment: You can cast the negative values. TControl.Perform(..,WPARAM(-1),...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a defect in the Delphi 7 header translations, one of many. This type is [documented on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx#WPARAM) like so:

> **WPARAM**
>
> A message parameter. This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows:
>
> ```
> typedef UINT_PTR WPARAM;
> ```

In turn, `UINT_PTR` is an unsigned integral type, whose size is the same as the platform pointer.

Around the time of the introduction of the 64 bit compiler, this defect was corrected and the Delphi declaration of the type became unsigned, to match the underlying platform API.

If you wish to pass a negative value, you should cast it. Like this:

```
WPARAM(-1)
```

Such casts are a necessary evil cause by the `SendMessage` API which presents a common interface for all message types. Sometimes you simply need to make your message payload fit with the available types. I would also comment that the `lParam` argument has type [`LPARAM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx#LPARAM) which is a pointer sized signed integer. This means that when decided how to pass additional data alongside a message you can opt between signed (`lParam`) and unsigned (`wParam`) types. Of course, if you want to pass two signed values, or two unsigned values then you need to cast.

In the case of `EM_LINEFROMCHAR` you might observe that `lParam` is not used. You might ask why the designers did not pass the character index in the signed `lParam` argument instead of the unsigned `wParam` argument. One possible reason is that `-1` is a sentinel value. By using the unsigned argument the character index can be any value between `0` and `$ffffffff - 1` (assuming 32 bit integers). This means that the valid range of the character index is twice as large as if a signed value was used. Now, if a signed value was used, it could be cast again for values greater than `$7fffffff` but it makes sense to require casting only for the special sentinel value.

Answer (score 1):

The type is WPARAM, which is defined as UINT_PTR. If you want to pass negative values anyway, you can pass e.g.

```
WPARAM(-1)
```

and that should work as expected.